# JavaScript regex woes

Tags: javascript, regex

So I have come up with the following Regex: `/((?:\\u2B1C)+)|((?:\\u2B1B)+)/g`.

It is to be used to parse the string of Unicode characters below - comprimised of `\u2B1C` and `\u2B1B`. I want it to match as many of either in a row and then pass it to the replace function. I have tested it over at http://regexpal.com/ and it matches my input text perfectly.

However when I go to use it in a `String.replace()` nothing happens whatsoever, I receive no console message, no nada.

Can someone point me in the right direction here?

### In usage:

```
var output = s.replace(/((?:\\u2B1C)+)|((?:\\u2B1B)+)/g, function(match) {
  console.log(match);
  return '%c' + match;
});
```

### Text to match:

```
"\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C
\u2B1C\u2B1B\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1B\u2B1B\u2B1B\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C
\u2B1C\u2B1B\u2B1B\u2B1B\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1B\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C
\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1B\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C
\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C
\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C
\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C
\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C
\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C
\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C
\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C
\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C
\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C
\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C
\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C
\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C
\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C
\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C
\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C
\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C\u2B1C"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Don't escape the backslashes:

```
/((?:\u2B1C)+)|((?:\u2B1B)+)/g
```

or simply (you don't need all these groups):

```
/\u2B1C+|\u2B1B+/g
```

Since you're only matching single (repeated) characters, you can also use a [character class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html): (thanks to Niet the Dark Absol (what's an Absol?)

```
/([\u2B1B\u2B1C])\1*/g
```

Comment: Ah thank you... I had to escape them in one of my earlier attempts (using Regex Object) I didn't even think to try that. Works beautifully. Surely I need the alternation because I want only blocks of the same character to be included in each match?

Comment: The character class won't work, because it's trying to match the same character in a row. However, you could do this: `/([\u2B1B\u2B1C])\1*/`

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol Thanks that works also... is there a reason I should use one over the other? Perhaps performance? Total Regex noob... that's the first time I've written one that did what I wanted.

Comment: No real reason, although personally I'd say my suggestion shows the intent just a little better, which is always a good idea with regexes.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol Can I be cheeky and ask if you know how to tell it to not match newlines also? Just `\n` none of that fancy stuff. I'm not quite sure what `\1*/` does (1 or more times?)

Comment: `\1` refers to the first subpattern - in this case, the parentheses containing the character class. Basically, whatever matches in that character class, it tries to match it again. `*` 0 or more times.